# Parse image from JSON in Android

Tags: android, json, image, parsing

I'm trying to get the first image shown in the following JSON:

```
{
    "hourly_forecast": [{
            "FCTTIME": {
                "hour": "0",
                "hour_padded": "00",
                "min": "00",
                "sec": "0",
                "year": "2013",
                "mon": "10",
                "mon_padded": "10",
                "mon_abbrev": "Oct",
                "mday": "30",
                "mday_padded": "30",
                "yday": "302",
                "isdst": "0",
                "epoch": "1383087600",
                "pretty": "12:00 AM CET on October 30, 2013",
                "civil": "12:00 AM",
                "month_name": "October",
                "month_name_abbrev": "Oct",
                "weekday_name": "Wednesday",
                "weekday_name_night": "Wednesday Night",
                "weekday_name_abbrev": "Wed",
                "weekday_name_unlang": "Wednesday",
                "weekday_name_night_unlang": "Wednesday Night",
                "ampm": "AM",
                "tz": "",
                "age": ""
            },

            "temp": {
                "english": "47",
                "metric": "8"
            },
            "dewpoint": {
                "english": "44",
                "metric": "6"
            },
            "condition": "Mostly Cloudy",
            "icon": "mostlycloudy",
            "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/nt_mostlycloudy.gif",

            "fctcode": "3",
            "sky": "71",
            "wspd": {
                "english": "11",
                "metric": "18"
            },
            "wdir": {
                "dir": "SW",
                "degrees": "231"
            },
            "wx": "",
            "uvi": "0",
            "humidity": "86",
            "windchill": {
                "english": "-9998",
                "metric": "-9998"
            },
            "heatindex": {
                "english": "-9998",
                "metric": "-9998"
            },
            "feelslike": {
                "english": "47",
                "metric": "8"
            },
            "qpf": {
                "english": "",
                "metric": ""
            },
            "snow": {
                "english": "",
                "metric": ""
            },
            "pop": "10",
            "mslp": {
                "english": "29.93",
                "metric": "1013"
            }
        },
```

This repeats for every hour, but I only need the first image. How do I make an `AyncTask` that gives me back just the first image found by the tag "icon_url"?

Code that I have so far:

```
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
    String response = null;
    String url = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/apikey/hourly/q/CA/"
            + toStation + ".json";
    Time now = new Time();
    now.setToNow();
    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

        ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        response = client.execute(httpGet, handler);
        JSONArray list = new JSONArray(response);

        for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject wheatherObj = list.getJSONObject(i);
            Wheather wheather = new Wheather(wheatherObj);
            if(wheather.getTime()==now.hour+"") {
                <what needs to be here>
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is your code so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
URL bmpUrl = new URL(wheatherObj.getString("icon_url"));
final Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bmpUrl.openConnection().getInputStream());
```

Should get you your Bitmap. To set it into an ImageView you can do this after:

```
final ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
      imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to close your connections in a try/finally.

Comment: I put the bitmap decoder in the place of "<what needs to be here>" but how do i get the bmp variable to another activity?

Comment: Yes, that should go in the "<what needs to be here>". How are you starting that second activity? You could just save the URL string and pass it into the new activity in an extra in the intent then have that new activity decode the bmp whenever it needs it.